# Incorrect java version when trying to build android sources

Tags: android-source

I am trying to build android sources, and am getting a weird error. I have chosen java using

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
$ sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

AND

```
$ update-alternatives --config java
$ update-alternatives --config javac
```

When I run `make -j4` I get

```
Your version is: java version "1.7.0_72".
The correct version is: Java SE 1.6.
```

When I run `sudo make -j4` I get

```
Your version is: java version "1.6.0_33".
The correct version is: Java SE 1.6.
```

On the [android source page](https://source.android.com/source/building-running.html)

```
Please follow the machine setup instructions at
    https://source.android.com/source/download.html
```

On the [OPENJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/install/) page, I ran the installs

```
jsiddharth@TheDEN:~/workspace/androidsource$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openjdk-6-jre is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.

jsiddharth@TheDEN:~/workspace/androidsource$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openjdk-6-jdk is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
```

**EDIT**
I have removed all java-7 from my destkop, and I have only installed `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk`. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use openjdk-6-jdk for all my AOSP and Cyanogenmod building and I never had errors. I'm not really sure why Google keep demanding the Oracle stuff but IMHO its not purely technical. So my advise is to comment the error generation in the makefile build/core/main.mk (look at the '#' comment):

```
ifeq ($(strip $(java_version)),)
$(info ************************************************************)
$(info You are attempting to build with the incorrect version)
$(info of java.)
$(info $(space))
$(info Your version is: $(java_version_str).)
$(info The required version is: $(required_version))
$(info $(space))
$(info Please follow the machine setup instructions at)
$(info $(space)$(space)$(space)$(space)https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html)
$(info ************************************************************)
#$(error stop)
endif
```